# How to save pdf with current look, for example correct rotation of pages

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, print-to-pdf

You can print it to a PDF, but change the orientation from Auto to Portrait.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Acrobat Reader DC. I can print the page to pdf, but to save the rotation of the view, I need to change the print rotation at the dialog to portrait.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).